# Puppeteer, property does not exist on type 'void | Browser'

Tags: typescript, jestjs, puppeteer

I am really new to Puppeteer so bear with me please.
I am writing some tests using Puppeteer, jest and typesript.

A test suite looks a bit like this:

```
// launch puppeteer with the required configuration
const boot = async (): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    browser = await puppeteer
      .launch({
        headless: false, // extension are allowed only in the head-full mode
        args: [
          `--disable-extensions-except=${extensionPath}`,
          `--load-extension=${extensionPath}`,
        ],
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

describe('pup', () => {
  // make sure the boot function is called before we start testing
  beforeAll(async (done) => {
    await boot();
    done();
  });

  afterAll(async (done) => {
    // TODO: this is no good but it'll avoid the error
    if (!browser) {
      return;
    }
    await browser.close();
    done();
  });

  test('something', async () => {
    // ERROR: Property 'newPage' does not exist on type 'void | Browser'
    const page = await browser.newPage();
  });
});
```

The problem I a facing is that then I try to call a function of the `browser` I got a typescript error as shown above.
I could check for every test if browser is not 'empty' (like I do in the `afterAll` function) but I really don't like it.

It seems a pretty easy issue to solve, but I can't find a solution that I like.
Is there a better way to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting Promise | void is in the case in which puppeteer.launch throws an exception.

You're handling the exception case twice - once in the async style and once in the promise style. You only need one or the other. I'll illustrate both style below:

Promise style (here we use .then for 'everything went fine' and .catch for errors):

```
let browser: Browser;

const boot = (): Promise<void> => {
  puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false, // extension are allowed only in the head-full mode
    args: [
      `--disable-extensions-except=${extensionPath}`,
      `--load-extension=${extensionPath}`,
    ],
  }).then(instance => {
    // This runs if successful
    browser = instance;
  }).catch((error: any) => {
    // This runs if error thrown
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Async/await style:

```
let browser: Browser;

const boot = (): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false, // extension are allowed only in the head-full mode
      args: [
        `--disable-extensions-except=${extensionPath}`,
        `--load-extension=${extensionPath}`,
      ],
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // Error thrown in try block is caught here - instead of catch
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

You should be using one form or the other. When you add a .catch to an expression that you are awaiting - if it throws then it's handled so your variable receives the return type of catch() - which is void.

```
function f() {
  return new Promise<number>((r, rej) => r(123));
}

async function asyncWithCatch() {
  const a = await f().catch(console.error);
  type A = typeof a; // number | void <- your issue
}

async function asyncNoCatch() {
  try { 
    const a = await f();
    type A = typeof a; // number <- what you want
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(a);
  }
}
```

[Here's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.8.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFASkQbwFCMQJwFMoR8kxCB3RABXzgFsYBnQgHjBAYCND8A%20FCnwAaAoQBWGALz8CKAIwAmAMxo0AbmwBfbNgCGzAJ6Rk4aPCSGTEAOowoACwDC%20qBEfosuRBATMoRH1EaSDKfQdkdAA6CDcPFD8wZjgAG0Jovnp8TR8oIwAHQkQAQRDEfKK4YCCNRAB6esROHj5EAB9EADc4GAATHT1rU1BIWAQg40gAOThXd08MHDwkgKDy-XDI1Fy8SuKy0P3q2oamlt58HSA) the above code in the TS playground

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I tried that too. But I get a `Type 'void | Browser' is not assignable to type 'Browser'` warning inside my `beforeAll`. But I solved casting it like this `as Browser;`

Comment: Sorry - my answer was actually incorrect. I see your problem now. Updated my answer

Comment: oh yes, your explanation now makes sense. Thank you!